# MS wants to reconnect outlook 2013 to Outlook.com. Did that, got duplicate accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Helped an old lady cope with pop-ups asking to reconnect Outlook 2013. Followed MS instructions. Result was two accounts in her name, old one's server is a long hyphenated hex string ending in @outlook.com, uses cached mode. New account server is eas.outlook.com. Accounts duplicate new mail and deletions of messages. We'd like to delete the duplicate account but fear that both will be deleted. Proposed solution is to export her data to a file, delete both accounts and start over. Will this work?
System is Windows 10 (10.0.14393 build 14393) in an HP 23-h024 64 bit machine with adequate memory and disk storage. Office is Home and Business 2013 15.0.4885.1001

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you seem to have the answer to your own question. All you need is a safe way of testing it.

That is simple. You can set up an additional Windows user account on that certain computer, start Outlook 2013 and connect to that certain Outlook.com account. You can also do this in another computer or a virtual machine.

Once you've ascertained that your data are indeed safe on the cloud and can sync with a brand-new Outlook without the risk of losing anything, you can delete the new Windows user account and its profile, go back to the original Windows user account, delete Outlook's configurations and start over.